# Payment Error: INVALID_REQUEST: The total of Item Amount via Mastercard payment method

Tags: magento2, store-credit

Getting error while applying store credit to checkout via Mastercard payment method
Payment Error: INVALID_REQUEST: The total of Item Amount, Tax Amount, Shipping and Handling Amount minus Discount Amount should total the Order Amount (500.00) but is 1000.00
[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the checkout page? Which store credit extension are you using?

Comment: I am using default extension of commerce cloud. Magento_CustomerBalance